# ImportError: cannot import name 'RGBColor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, colormath

I am trying to import this:

```
from colormath.color_objects import RGBColor
```

and I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RGBColor'
```

I am using Python 3.6 and the library colormath is installed.

Comment: @RoyaumelX use: from colormath.color_objects import BaseRGBColor

Comment: Why do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RGBColor` is a removed class from an old version of colormath.

From the v2.0.1 [release notes](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-colormath/2.0.1/python-colormath.pdf) (2014):

> Completely re-worked RGB handling. Each RGB space now has its own
>   class, inheriting from BaseRGBColor. Consequently, RGBColor is no
>   more. In most cases, you can substitute RGBColor with sRGBColor during
>   your upgrade.

And if you check the [current documentation](https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/color_objects.html), you'll see there is indeed no `RGBColor`. Try `sRGBColor` instead.

Comment: This works.
Actually, this is my use case:
```from colormath.color_objects import LabColor, sRGBColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color

rgb = sRGBColor.new_from_rgb_hex('#c6c3c1')
lab = convert_color(rgb, LabColor)```